# If people forgot how to write, how would the world be affected?

Tags: society, magic, language, written-material

Suppose that you woke up tomorrow and the world had lost all memory of written communication including how to make paper and how to use pen, pencil, typewriters, colors, keyboards, basically any means of written communication (A selective amnesia kind of a thing). How would the world be affected ?

They could still read and whatever written accounts are there, they still exist but the people cannot make paper or use anything to write even if they read the procedure to create it.

Comment: What about scribbling in mud? Braille? Pictograms?

Comment: Is it permanent?

Comment: @Mormacil: you have lost the ability to convey things by writing...so all of those fall under it...

Comment: @Molot: Yes, it is permanent...

Comment: @user96551 You are aware voice to text is a thing right?

Comment: There is no way for a population to be able to read but unable to write. If one can read they can also write, maybe slowly, maybe painfully, but they definitely _can_. Humans have this amazing capacity of _drawing_ shapes; if a person can read they can also draw the shapes of the characters.

Comment: Would voice to text programs be considered a form of writing or is that not writing since the computer is doing the actual writing for them and they are just talking.

Comment: @JarredAllen So somehow this selective amnesia is going to also make people forget how to talk, but only when they're talking to their computers? I'm sorry, but the question only ever says that people cannot write. Not, that people cannot write and they can't talk to computers.

Comment: I am sorry but here we have another case of "[I thought of a cool concept, please come up with all the consequences for me](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/)". A high concept is always a good start for building a world. But it is **you** that need to build that world, not us. We are here to help you if you have questions or problems when building that world. And the way your question is phrased, I do not see that you have actually started on building on this concept. However...

Comment: There is a way for you to just try out the idea around a bit with other world-builders, and that is to visit our nifty chat: [The Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor). If you bounce your idea around there and see what happens. It should give you good inspiration to get going on building your World of Dyslexia. :)

Comment: Questions asking "What is the effect of event x on society?" are often closed as too broad.

Answer (score 4):

### This is already a thing. For some people.

For the blind who have not learned to read braille (or don't have a special braille keyboard) the internet is still navigable, they can still write emails and send messages, they can still make phonecalls. All this without ever typing or writing down a single letter. Sounds like magic right? Atleast that's what you'd think from reading some of the current answers saying this sudden (very) selective amnesia would lead to societal collapse.

It's called [voice to text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition). I'm sure you are all aware of its existance, some of you probably use it from time to time to issue commands to your smartphones. It's even easily accessible on pratically all modern operating systems.

---

Now while not totally accurate, since the people of your world can still read, they'd be able to easily correct any mistakes that do come along while using it. Further more since improving the software would now be somewhat a priority, it is likely that it would be perfected within a few years from the onset of this event.

---

So there, far from spelling out the end times or the fall of the developped world, all this would really mean is everybody obnoxiously talking outloud to their phones and computers all the time.

Comment: People would still need to write the codes for their phones and computers though.

Comment: @PedroGabriel Well, not really... We already have mostly functional voice to text. So, if they wanted to improve on the software, they can use already existing software to do so. I do grant you that it will take a bit longer to "write" each line of code down since they'd have to individually speak outloud every character, but it is still entirely feasible.

Answer (score 2):

People would be hit the hardest in more developed areas, but areas with poor literacy would be barely impacted at all.

The internet falls very quickly because sysadmins are now no longer able to write any commands to keep their computers operating, and you can also only navigate by clicking links, so most of the internet would be inaccessible to most people. This would cause big problems for most businesses. Similarly, stores would close due to an inability to keep records, which would greatly reduce the supply of necessary supplies, such as food.

Other forms of communication would also collapse. Phone calls can't happen since you can't input phone numbers, all forms of mail become useless. Some communication would still exist, like radio, but it would not be enough to stave off the big societal problems that happen in the short-term.

Developed areas would quite quickly fall to riots as a result of the closures of businesses due to the problems that arise from this causing a lack of places to buy basic necessities such as food. Within a few weeks, all developed civilizations would be decimated.

In the long term, someone will invent some system that serves the same function as writing has for people so far, and then humanity will start to come back from the major problems that it faces, but humanity will have already suffered big losses by then.

Answer (score 1):

I assume audio logs would be dominant. Not sure if you'd block voice-to-text protocols on computers. If you did making new audio books would be a tedious job of connecting audio files but doable.

You'd share audio files with people, record message. Perhaps video would be part of it. It would replace most things we use writing for. Messages to people, notes to self, lessons in school.

Sure explaining math will be an issue. That will probably contribute to a slow decline in overal knowledge but audio logs will slow it down tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

An odd side effect would be the return of epic poetry.

One of the more tedious things about great works like the Iliad and the Odessy is the framework.  How many times does Homer use phrases like "Rosy Fingered Dawn" causing millions of high school students to yawn instantly.  These archaic phrases serve a purpose though.  They are used as story beats, helping the person reciting them to stay on track within the story.

This is common throughout civilizations.  Our brains respond differently to lyrics than they do to straight up prose.  We can memorize snippets of a song very quickly, while we have a hard time remembering even short passages from books.  Many civilizations that relied on the Oral tradition have their history bound up in songs and poems.  A lot of what we know about Norse mythology is bound up in the [Poetic Edda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetic_Edda) which goes back to the Codex Regius which may be tied to the Elder Edda and other Eddic poems.  Lots of Navajo folklore is passed down the generation in their songs.

So as civilization as we know it crumbles, we can light a fire and tell each other more consistent stories in verse, rather than that kind of painful scene about "Star Wars" in that movie "Reign of Fire".